# Transferred money to an Intermediary Bank Account by mistake

Tags: money-transfer, international-transfer

I am having a problem with transferring money to pay for my tuition fees.

The university has sent me these payment instructions:

[image]

I have transferred the fees directly to the intermediary bank account instead of the beneficiary by mistake.

What are the correct steps to get my money back from the intermediary bank?
Who is the owner of the intermediary bank account?

---

As an update, I got the money back within 2 weeks to my bank account. I think because they don't expect any money transfer directly to that account as it's an intermediary account, so they just reversed the process back.

Didn't have to contact the intermediary bank for that (I mean I tried but could not reach them anyways.)

My own bank didn't have anything to do, same for Western Union.

Comment: So you didn't include the beneficiary information, but just sent the payment directly to Riyad Bank? I suggest you contact Riyad Bank and give them the details.

Comment: Specifically, the bank will have these funds they have no idea what to do with. You can facilitate the transfer, probably, through contacting them.

Comment: What kind of a school has you transfer tuition to an account in the name of Western Union?  It should be going into a bank account in the name of the university!  Or else Western Union could be an intermediary, and there should be a Western Union account in the name of the university.

Comment: It’s Macquarie University.

Comment: Could you solve the problem ? I am having the same problem and trying all ways to solve it but not succeed yet

Comment: I would contact all parties listed here. Your bank should be able to initiate a request to have the funds redeposited in your account; be prepared to wait a week or more.

Answer (score 2):

1. Contact your school's finance department. I'm sure this isn't the first time it's happened and they'll tell you the next steps to take.
2. If you can't reach someone or they don't know the answer, contact the *intermediary bank*. Explain your situation. They should be able to help.
3. If for some reason 1 and 2 don't work, contact the beneficiary bank. Again, explain your situation and they should be able to help.
4. I would expect something above to work, but your last chance is to contact the bank you transferred from.

You're not going to lose your money. You just have to get into contact with the right people to work out your situation.

Comment: As Justin commented already, I would change the order. Contacting the intermediary bank is most effective, because they have the money.

Comment: @JanDoggen I would tend to agree, but in this case I would definitely contact the school first. Like I said, I’m sure they’ve dealt with this before and could have specific steps. They also might have a direct representative at the bank to contact.