# Wire transfer to an intermediary bank account

Tags: wire-transfer, cad-canadian-dollar

I sent money from a bank that doesn't have a space for intermediary bank, so I put the intermediary bank statement information where the beneficiary bank information is supposed to be.  I  don't know what will happen now.

Comment: As it stands this question is likely to get closed as “unclear what you are asking”. Can you comment or edit the post with more information, explaining what you have done so far (from the start of the transaction) and exactly what has happened? Also, have you asked your bank directly?

Comment: The wire transfer payment slip you posted - which I won't link to again as it contains personal information - shows that the payment is to a country that is a commonplace source of scams. What exactly is the transfer for, and who gave you the intermediary and beneficiary bank details?

Comment: The transfer was meant for construction, and my cousin gave me the intermediary and beneficiary details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transferred money to an Intermediary Bank Account by mistake](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/108935/transferred-money-to-an-intermediary-bank-account-by-mistake)

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to be worrying about intermediary banks, routing is the banks' problem. This is the same as sending a letter, you wouldn't write on the letter a list of all the towns where the mail has to go through to arrive at the destiation.

Your money is now probably going to the intermediary bank, who has no idea what to with it, and doesn't know you. They will either reject it, or just wait until instructions come in.
You should contact the bank you sent it from, and ask them to follow up and rectify the issue, otherwise it could be a long time until you see it back.

Comment: Can my bank instruct the intermidiary bank to send the money to where it was supposed to go, because the beneficiary bank is linked with it

Comment: Some banks do require you to explicitly state an intermediary bank, usually for international transfers where the bank you are sending to does not have access to an international wire network, so they do the transfer through another bank in the same country... Here is an example of such a wire form (not with a bank I use but one I know who supports it) https://www.tdcommercialbanking.com/document/PDF/wbb/help/English/pdfs/Wire-Payments-Fixed-Templates-Request-Form.pdf
You need a form that supports this to do it and if you do not have it on your form it wont work...

Answer (score 0):

You are in a bit of a pickle now, you should have asked your bank how to send a wire with an explicit intermediary. You usually need a different form for such a transfer as they are relatively rare and only used for a few receiving banks in certain countries. ([Here is an example of a wire form for use with sending via an intermediary](https://www.tdcommercialbanking.com/document/PDF/wbb/help/English/pdfs/Wire-Payments-Fixed-Templates-Request-Form.pdf), each bank usually has its own form for this.)

Its possible you were supposed to put "For further credit (FFC) to (Final bank and account)" in the memo line. Or make a call to the bank in advance, or fill out another form to explain what the payment was for. It depends which bank was the intermediary and sender.

Currently your money will be sent to the intermediary bank with no additional instructions. They will either return it or keep it. You may still be able to salvage the situation by calling or writing to the intermediary bank and your own bank with the payment reference to provide them with instructions on how to further credit the money to the final recipient.

Otherwise if you do not have a payment reference to refer to or another way to identify the payment you will have to wait and hope they will return the money to you after a waiting period of not hearing from you.